# Countdown timer swift

Tags: swift, nsdate

I am developing a countdown timer in my application, but I do not know why it isn't working.

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
let userCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let requestedComponent: NSCalendarUnit = [
//NSCalendarUnit.Month,
//NSCalendarUnit.Day,
NSCalendarUnit.Hour,
NSCalendarUnit.Minute,
NSCalendarUnit.Second

]

  func printTime()
{
   formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss a"
    //let startTime = NSDate()
    let startTime = formatter.dateFromString("05/12/16 0:00:00 a")
    let endTime = formatter.dateFromString("12/25/16 8:00:00 a")
    let timeDifference = userCalendar.components(requestedComponent, fromDate: startTime!, toDate: endTime!, options: [])
    TimeLabel.text = " \(timeDifference.hour)Hours \(timeDifference.minute)Minutes \(timeDifference.second) Seconds"
}


    let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(printTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    timer.fire()
```

If I leave:

```
let startTime = NSDate()
```

and comment

```
let startTime = formatter.dateFromString("05/12/16 0:00:00 a")
```

it works perfect, but it starts from the current time and date at the moment.
I need a specific date and time, in my case is "05/12/16 0:00:00 a" and the time should start counting down from that date and hour, not from now.

Comment: Do not use `dateFromString` to form a date. Use date components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason nothing is happening is because you're always comparing the same two dates: `startTime` and `endTime`. The difference between these two dates will always be exactly the same. If you want there to be a gradual countdown, you'll need to change one or the other accordingly. The reason the `NSDate()` version works is because `startTime` is changing—to whatever the current date is.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood it very well now.
In my case I want to disable a button for 8 hours (08:00:00) and when this time is over I want to enable the button again.
Do you have an idea how to do it?

Comment: I would do something where you store the time that the button should be re-enabled as an `NSDate` somewhere, and check on your regular basis whether that date's `timeIntervalSinceNow()` is greater than 0. If it isn't, the button can be re-enabled.